# How do I specify a private_vlan in a python api softlayer create_instance call

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to order a vsi using the python api specifying private and public vlans that I am already using but the call fails.

```
>>> client = SoftLayer.Client(username=SL_USERNAME, api_key=SL_API_KEY,endpoint_url=SoftLayer.API_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT)
>>> mgr = SoftLayer.VSManager(client)
>>> vsi
{'dedicated': False, 'disks': ['100', '25'], 'hourly': True, 'domain':'vmonic.local', 'private': False, 'cpus': 1, 'private_vlan': 123, 'public_vlan':1234, 'datacenter': 'sjc03', 'ssh_keys': ['12345', '23456'], 'hostname':'ansible-server', 'os_code': 'CENTOS_LATEST', 'local_disk': True, 'memory': 1024}
>>> mgr.create_instance(**vsi)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/SoftLayer/managers/vs.py",line 534, in
create_instance
inst = self.guest.createObject(self._generate_create_dict(**kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 373, in
call_handler
return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 341, in call
return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 237, in call
return self.transport(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py",  line 187, in
__call__
raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError:
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Could not obtain network VLAN with id
#123.
```

The vlan and ssh key ids are sanitized from the true values in the pasted output above.

I can create a vsi using the SL portal specifying the same vlans that fail in the api call. What do I need to do in the python api to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified that your template is working fine, The public and private vlans were set successfully, According to the exception that you have, the vlan "123" doesn't exist, It is necessary specify the network vlan identifiers in public and private vlans.

Please, double check that "123" and "1234" are **network vlan identifiers**.

The following script will help to get vlans for a specific datacenter (e.g. sjc03)

```
"""
List Vlans for specific datacenter
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declare the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
mgr = SoftLayer.NetworkManager(client)
# Define Datacenter name
dc = 'sjc03'

try:
    result = mgr.list_vlans(datacenter=dc)
    print(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Error. "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

> Updated

```
"""
Get Vlan from vlanNumber
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declare the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
mgr = SoftLayer.NetworkManager(client)

# Define Vlan number
vlanNumber = 966

try:
    result = mgr.list_vlans(vlan_number=vlanNumber)
    print(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Error. "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Comment: Hi Ruber, as I noted, the values 123 and 1234 were "sanitized" (i.e. changed from the actual values that we are using) for purposes of posting this question. The actual vlans are 966 and 1235. Interestingly using your code returns no valid vlans in dc sjc03, even though I current have vsi deployments in that dc on vlans 966 and 1235 and I can successfully deploy to them via the portal/UI. EDIT: I assumed you worked at SoftLayer, but just checked your profile and see that you don't... but appreciate your help anyway.

Comment: My Apologizes for the misunderstanding, anyway I think, you are specifying the "vlanNumber" instead of "id" from the vlan. Please see the updated section, the script that I attached will return the id from the "vlanNumber", you need to use that "id" value

Comment: The [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com/) shows the "vlanNumber" at the moment to place an order(But internally it works with the network vlan identifier)

Comment: No need to apologize, and thanks for your help. You are correct in that I was using the actual vlan number (vlanNumber)... and using the id field resolves the issue. Thanks again.